# Why my catch block is not executed when error occurs

Tags: node.js, express-jwt

I'm currently working with `express-jwt`, but having some problems. Instead of giving me json response for error, I get html error display in postman. How to pass `express-jwt` errors in catch block.

```
router.get('/profile', ejwt({
    secret: config.JWT_SECRET
}), (req, res) => {
    try {
        res.json({
            httpResponse: 'OK',
            statusCode: 200,
            user: req.user
        });
    } catch (err) {
        let newResponse = new response.httpResponseMessage('Unauthorized', 401, response.msg.ProhibitedAccess);
        return res.status(newResponse.statusCode).send(newResponse);
    }

});
```

This is the result I wanted

```
{
     httpResponse: 'Unauthorized',
     statusCode: 401,
}
```

Comment: `res.json` is an async call - you can't wrap it with try-catch block like you do, try something like: `res.json(...).then(...).catch(e => ...)`

Comment: Already tried that but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
router.get('/profile',ejwt({secret: config.JWT_SECRET}),(err,req,res)=>{
    if(res){
       res.json({
         httpResponse: 'OK',
         statusCode: 200,
         user: req.user
       })
    }
    if(err){
      throw err
    }  
})
```

this could help you

Comment: Hey @ChristianAngeloMSulit i have edited my code try this

Comment: Nope not working again gives me an error. I already fixed the my problem by adding this before module.exports = router 

router.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    if (err.name === 'UnauthorizedError') {
        res.status(401).json({
            "error": err.name + ": " + err.message
        })
    }
});

Comment: Thank you for giving time to this thread I appreciate it man.

Comment: your welcome @ChristianAngeloMSulit nice to hear that your problems is solved

Comment: @ChristianAngeloMSulit i have edited again and  the changes , bracket problem , if you get free time pls check it , i think this don't give you error

Comment: TypeError: res.json is not a function